# ui:repeat is not rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I wrote a web program in the Netbeans IDE 7.1.2 in java server faces 
and I have a problem with `ui:repeat` tag

```
<h:form id="arrangmentForm" rendered="false" >
  <ui:repeat value="#{arrangement.arItemArrangment}" var="itemArrangment"  >
    <h:panelGrid   style="position: absolute;top:#{itemArrangment.place.top / 10}px;left: #{itemArrangment.place.left/10}px;height: 30px;width:30px">
      <h:commandLink  id="linkItemArrangment" actionListener="#{arrangement.showbtnArrangement()}" style="text-decoration: none;color: black">
        <p:graphicImage value="../images/#{itemArrangment.place.objType}.jpg"  />
        <h:outputText value="#{itemArrangment.place.objTitle}" />
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{itemArrangment.gethOrder().gethOrdersTotal()}" />
        <br />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{itemArrangment}" target="#{arrangement.selectPlace}" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

This code works fine in Netbeans.

When I tried to deploy my program to a web server (Tomcat7, Glassfish open source and enterprise edition) the `ui` tag didn't work, though, and in my web browser I just receive the `form` tag and nothing else.

Comment: Make sure your header has the `xmlns:ui` definition. Please post all your page code, check that your web.xml has the filter for *.xhtml and you're calling the page with .xhtml suffix

Answer (score 0):

You have `rendered="false"` in your h:form so nothing is display. It's the normal behavior.

If you want to display the content of the form remove the `rendered="false"`

Comment: How did the OP then receive "the form tag and nothing else"?

Comment: @BalusC I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: If the form wasn't rendered, then the OP wouldn't have received the form tag at all. I think the code is actually a careless copypaste of an experimentation.